# Gradle composite build with custom gradle plugin fails in IntelliJ: "Could not find method api() for arguments"

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a Gradle composite build project which contains a custom Gradle plugin. This project builds fine when using Gradle CLI, but IntelliJ fails.

I tried a few different variations on the plugin version within the `resolutionStrategy` block: `org.test:test-plugin:0.0.1` and `test-plugin:test-plugin.gradle.plugin:0.0.1` as described here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers - both of those work from the CLI; changing to invalid values ("blah:blah") causes a failure.

I've made a sample Github project that contains the code to reproduce, here: https://github.com/mwmitchell/intellij-gradle-plugin-composite-build-bug along with instructions to reproduce and a workaround. The workaround is something that's not really feasible for me, as it requires repeating configuration code (dependencies, plugins etc.) and I have many, many projects that require the same/common configuration.

I would expect IntelliJ to load the project successfully, just like the CLI does. It seems like IntelliJ is loading the sub-project (`:project-1:library-a`) before the parent (`:project-1`), such that the `java-library` is not actually applied to the sub-project when it's evaluated.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've tried Gradle 4.10.2 and Gralde 4.10.3, and my IntelliJ version is:

`IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-183.4886.37, built on December 17, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6`

Comment: I've updated the README.md in the sample project on Github to show how publishing to maven local allows IntelliJ to successfully load the project. Although IntelliJ itself is unable to publishToMavenLocal due to a duplicate root project name.

Comment: It looks like when you build the main project from command line the `:project-1:library-a` project is not included into build: only one `settings.gradle` is allowed for the Gradle project (and gradle uses only the root's project `settings.gradle` file). When I import `project-1` project into IDE it also builds fine for me.

Comment: The approach I'm taking is to use `includeBuild` though, which from the Gradle examples/docs show that projects loaded with `includeBuild` are treated separately. Here's the example I originally followed: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/compositeBuilds/basic/groovy -- and then this one as well: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/compositeBuilds/plugin-dev

Comment: For Gradle IntelliJ Plugin users: similar thing happens on 0.x->1.x update, basically instead of `pluginName 'value'`, `version 'value'` etc you have to use `pluginName.set('value')`, `version.set('value')` etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the sample project! Indeed, it is an issue in IntelliJ IDEA, see [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208906).

Answer (score -2):

Gradle projects can have only one `settings.gradle`. You can include subproject "library-a" with `include 'project-1:library-a'` in the main `settings.gradle`.

Comment: Hi, I left a comment above about `includeBuild` vs `include`. From my understanding, `includeBuild` is supposed to provide the ability to have a composite build of independent projects. I left a few references to show more examples from the Gradle Github repo.